# MPU6050: Setting Gyro Output Range Throws of Positional Reading

Tags: mpu6050

I am using the MPU6050 in conjunction with an Arduino and Jeff Rowberg's i2cdev library, and my project requires that the gyro rate outputs be more precise than the default setting, which is 1/16.4 of a degree (+/-2000 deg/sec range). The gyro outputs can be changed with `mpu.setFullScaleGyroRange(uint8_t range)` for which I passed in `MPU6050_GYO_FS_500` for range to get a higher precision

In this project, I also need the YPR position, which I obtain through `mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer)` and `mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q)` and `mpu.dmpGetYawPitchRoll(ypr, &q, &gravity)`.

The problem is with the new gyro output range, the YPR position changes drastically when the MPU is being rotated and slowly catches up again once the MPU is held still. I think there is an error in the filter that combines the gyro and accel data that is making the gyro to sensitive. Maybe the DMP is dividing the GYRO rate data by the default sensitivity factor (16.4) when it should be dividing by the new one (131)?

**How can I get accurate YPR readings without delay?**

Here is a screenshot of the data. The axis aren't labeled, but the x-axis represents about 16 seconds of time. The blue line is the **gyro rate data**, and the pink line is the **roll position** of the MPU. The graph shows two rotations of the MPU.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, it appears that MPU6050 DMP code works like that once you change accelerometer and gyro scales.

Works better once you use +-2000 deg/sec and +-2g scaling settings.

```
    mpu.setFullScaleGyroRange(MPU6050_GYRO_FS_2000);
    mpu.setFullScaleAccelRange(MPU6050_ACCEL_FS_2);
```

The issue lies in the way "DMP" inner logic fuses data, i suppose it has "constants" that are tuned for these settings only.

In case you need both "changed settings" and "yaw\pitch\roll" data, you might want to implement sensor data fusion by yourself or use existing libs.

The easiest i may suggest would be implementing Complementary Filter.
More complex, yet accurate would be using Kalman Filter, all depends on time and patience you have to research those topics :)